# The only good point of Angular signals is "Use functions in html template"?

Tags: angular, signals

After read lots of articles and test those demos myself, I assume that the only good point of signals is "Use functions in html template and it won`t cause performance issue".

Maybe only is a strong word, or at least it is one of the biggest advantage of signals.

Is there any other good point if I refactor my code with signals? If that is the only good point, I will not bother.